# Trying to call js function from php and pass php html string as argument

Tags: javascript, php

Here is the problem which I am facing.

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.insertCartInHeader({$cart});</script>";
```

$cart variable is holding HTML block of code.
I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Solution?

```
window.insertCartInHeader = function(cart){ 
    console.log(cart)
    var list = $("#top-links").append('<ul id="cart-header"></ul>').find('#cart-header');
    list.append('<li>'+cart+'</li>');
}
```

Here is the string which I am passing

```
'<div id="cart">


  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="heading dropdown-toggle">

  <div class="pull-left flip"><h4></h4></div><span id="cart-total">0 item(s) - £0.00</span></button>


  <ul class="dropdown-menu">


    <li>

      <p class="text-center">Your shopping cart is empty!</p>

    </li>


  </ul>

</div>

' (length=402)
```

Comment: Why the curly braces? Strings are wrapped in quotes.

Comment: show insertCartInHeader please

Comment: Did you just edit your question but ignore my comment...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add quotes ("), to let javascript know it's a string, and you should use `addslashes`, since you may have classes or attributes in that html.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.insertCartInHeader(\"". addslashes($cart) . "\");</script>";
```

Without addslashes something like this, won't work:

```
$html = '<h1 class="hi">It works</h1>';
```

For multiline html, this should work.

```
str_replace("\n", "\\", addslashes($cart));
```

You can improve that replace, but you get the idea.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: I tried it with my HTML, and it works, post the entire string in $cart.

Comment: @Nikanor I believe you're still having an Issue because your code is multiline. you need to escape newlines with "\".

Comment: just succeded with tilda characters around {$cart}. Thanks for the tip, yea multiline is the problem here.